# How to store and delete matching files as well as directories in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I need to store matching files and directory names in a single variable in shell script

```
log_dir=`echo $line | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $1}'`
pattern=`echo $line | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $2}'`
days=`echo $line | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $3}'`
flag=`echo $line | awk -F "$delimiter" '{print $4}'`
now=$(date +%s)

matching_files=`find $log_dir/$pattern`
for f in $matching_files ; do
 //code
done
```

however i am getting below error

```
find: `magsubmit_*': No such file or directory
matching_files=
```

after listing i need to delete both matching files and directories as well can i do it using single command? instead of rmf and rm -rf?

how to achieve this?

Comment: what's in `$line`? Can you post an example?

Comment: also: please remove the lines `days=...`, `flag=...` and `now=...` in the example as they are not needed to explain the problem

Comment: In my view, the neatest way to deal with such things is often to replace your `matching_files=$(find "$log_dir/"$pattern)` material with: `find "$log_dir/"$pattern -exec bash script.sh {} +` where `script.sh` is a shell script, possibly created for the purposes of this single command, that contains the code in your `for f in $matching_files; do … done` command, working over the arguments it is given (so `for f in "$@"`). This mechanism handles weird characters (blanks, newlines, etc) in the file names. Not everyone agrees with this; there often seems to be a requirement to do it with one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process your files and directories one by one, you could do this in Bash 4.0+:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob

pattern="your_pattern_goes_here"
for f in $log_dir/**/$pattern; do
  # matching files
done

for d in $log_dir/**/$pattern/; do
  # matching directories
done
```

I would prefer Jonathan's approach since it is more efficient.